# "User is not enrolled in Duo Security" after adding a security key

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, multi-factor-authentication, yubico, yubikey, duosecurity

**I succesfully added a YubiKey to Snowflake MFA:**

[image: Adding a security key]

**Next time I try to login I immediately get following "User is not enrolled in Duo Security. Contact your local system administrator." error:**

[image: User is not enrolled in Duo Security. Contact your local system administrator.]

After inputting my username and password, I expect the site to ask me to touch my YubiKey. Instead I immediately get the error described above.

How can I setup Snowflake MFA using a YubiKey security key?

Our local admin disabled my MFA and I repeated the steps and I got the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not available on Snowflake side as of now.
I do agree there is a bit of confusion the fact that you are allowed to enroll with Yubikey but then fail to authenticate.

We do have an internal improvement request pending for this feature. I don't know a timeline yet but you can reach out to your Snowflake representative if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality might not be available with Snowflake, you can always enable Single Sign-on with your Identity provider and enable the yubi on the IDP end.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has removed that "Security Key" option for all regions to avoid this problem. That option for Snowflake MFA is not supported at the moment